# Help me understand this UI jargon

Tags: user-interface, air, rich-internet-application

From an [interview](http://www.flashmagazine.com/community/detail/balsamiq_mockups_-_a_solid_case_for_air/) with [Peldi Guilizzoni](http://www.peldi.com/blog/), the creator of [Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/)--an Adobe AIR application for creating mockups:

> **And then you started working on the
>   first version Balsamiq Mockups. Was
>   there any hurdles in the development
>   process?**
>
> Ha! There's always hurdles, it's part
>   of the fun of coding isn't it?
>
> Let me think. I think I rewrote the
>   foundation classes (the Model, the
>   Input Manager, the base UI Component,
>   etc) a few times until I was happy
>   with them. First I started with each
>   UI control handle the mouse events for
>   moving and resizing itself, then moved
>   all the mouse handling to a
>   transparent InputManager canvas that
>   sits on top of the view (similar to
>   what I had done for Connect's
>   whiteboard). I also had to learn and
>   digest all the different options for
>   run-time skinning before I was able to
>   create a strategy that worked for my
>   tool, which took a while.

- Is foundation classes a common term for the core classes in a framework?
- Are "Model, UI Component, Input Manager" common themes in user interface development and what do they comprise of exactly?
- What does he mean when he says he "moved the mouse handling to a transparent InputManager canvas on top of the view"? What is the view and the InputManager canvas.
- Why does he do runtime skinning? Can't the skinning be done before hand? What other options are available that he could have explored?

I am trying to get a handle on his design architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the question. To your first point, well yes. Why are you nit picking this guy? His application is pretty good. MFC == Microsoft Foundation Classes. To the second, I those are pretty straightforward, they roughly approximate to a MVC, it's just a variation on a similar pattern. As far as the third, well it's specific to his application; you would probably need to know a little more about how development occurs in AIR to know exactly what he means. But in general it doesn't sound very difficult to understand. For the last, I don't know. Ask him. :) It's a really neat application.

He was also interviewed on the Startup Success Podcast:

http://startuppodcast.wordpress.com/tag/balsamiq-mockups/

Comment: I don't think he's referring to MFC when he says foundation classes as this is Adobe specific. When I read Model I too though MVC, but I am trying to get a better handle on his architecture design.

Comment: I know that he's not referring to MFC. But I meant that it is not a "crazy" term for it. :)

Answer (score 2):

He is doing mock-ups. So for him, each UI Component is basically a rectangle (or other shape) that needs to be drawn and react to input. The input can come from different sources (mouse, keyboard, prepared for multi-touch?), so an Input Manager makes sense. In a mock-up, most components will have the same simple behavior, so extracting that to a separate object makes sense. In a mock-up it makes sense to change skins at run-time